# mimimum value of expression $a^2+b^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

> If $a,b$ are two non zero real numbers and $ab(a^2-b^2) = a^2+b^2,$ Then $\min(a^2+b^2)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $$ab=\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2-b^2}\Rightarrow a^2b^2=\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2-4a^2b^2}$$

Now Put $a^2+b^2=u$ and $a^2b^2=v,$ Then expression convert into $$v=\frac{u^2}{u^2-4v}\Rightarrow 4v^2-u^2v+u^2=0$$

For real roots, $\bf{Discriminant \geq 0}$

$$u^4-16u^2\geq 0\Rightarrow u^2(u^2-16)\geq 0$$

So we get $$u^2\geq 16\Rightarrow u\geq 4\Rightarrow x^2+y^2\geq 4,$$

My question is can we solve it any other way (without Trigonometric substution),

If yes , Then plz explain here, Thanks

Comment: I see no trigonometric substitution here. And you are correct.

Comment: Wouldn't the minimum occur at $a=b=0$?

Comment: @bulbasaur I'd guess no since $a$ and $b$ are "two non zero real numbers".

Comment: In polar coordinates, the constraint is $\rho^2(\rho^2\sin4\theta-4)=0$, then indeed $\rho^2\ge4$.

Comment: The problem can be addressed with Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Lagrange multipliers lead to a monster at least as I can see it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: that's quite possible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Then, I suppose that I unproperly set the problem ! I shall restart my approach taking into account the fact that you say that this is feasible.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I meant, it's quite possible that it's a monster :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust. OK, I prefer this ! I misunderstood. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we let $z = a + b i$ then we get 
$$ab = \frac{ z^2 - \bar{z}^2}{4i}$$
$$a^2 - b^2 = \frac{ z^2 + \bar{z}^2}{2}$$
$$a^2 + b^2 = z \bar{z}$$

Thus your original equation can be rewritten as 
$$\frac{Im(z^4)}{4} = \frac{z^4 - \bar{z}^4}{8 i} = \frac{(z^2 - \bar{z}^2)(z^2 + \bar{z}^2)}{8i} = z \bar{z}$$

We have $\frac{\|z\|^4}{4} \geq \frac{Im(z^4)}{4} = \|z\|^2$, so $\|z\|^2 \geq 4$, as desired. This is achieved exactly when $z^4$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: Isn't this a trigonometric substitution ? (directly obtained in polar coordinates)

Comment: If you would rather not have the explicit polar coordaintes, you can argue that $\frac{\|z\|^4}{4} \geq \frac{Im(z^4}{4} = \|z\|^2$. Which implies that $\|z\|^2 \geq 4$, as desired.

The polar coordinates just make this arguement more transparent, they are not needed.

Comment: Yep, this was explictly requested by the OP.

Comment: I edited my reply to avoid explicit mention of trig functions.